# How to test an 7zip arhive?

Tags: c#, 7zip

I'm trying to test if an 7zip arhive is corrupted or not, I found a good reference to add to my project, it's called `SevenZipSharp.dll`, but I can't find a help file to show me how, does anyone know how to use this library or another method.

Comment: Doesn't the Intellisense help?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SevenZipExtractor Class (Class for extracting and getting information about 7-zip archives)

```
SevenZipExtractor zipfile=new SevenZipExtractor("path to your archive");
if (zipfile.Check())
{
MessageBox.Show("Your archive or zip is ok");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Your archive or zip is not ok");
}
```

Download the library from: http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com

The documentation for the library is present in a chm file. Check that for cross reference

Comment: that is exactly wath I did. and i got this error : " Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: library is invalid."

Comment: Found what was wrong! I had to download the dll's from the  SevenZipSharp.codeplex.com and set my references like this:SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"D:\C#\Librari Extra\7z.dll");

Comment: @XandrUu - So you were looking for *someone else* to write the code for you?

Comment: This is not a good test. If archive is password protected or if you select non-first volume in a multipart volume, it will show this error in that case too.

Answer (score 1):

The `SevenZipExtractor` class has a `Check` method that according to the XML doc:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the archive integrity test.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True is the archive is ok; otherwise, false.</returns>
```

The SevenZipSharp source code is available in the [CodePlex code repository](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/59007). Reviewing it should be able to answer any questions you have about the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [excellent (award-winning) article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx) by [Eugene Sichkar](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Eugene-Sichkar) on using 7Zip DLLs in C#.

This should help, if not, at least point you in the right direction.

Cheers!